# Tableau error when opening from server into local file

Tags: download, version, compatibility, tableau-api

When I try to download a Tableau file from the server it gives me the error

`Errors occured while trying to load the workbook "C:\Users\mjones\AppData\Local\TableauTemp\0rfcxdjblahblah\test1.twbx". The load was not able to complete suxccessfully.`

Then when I click on Show Details I get

```
This file was created by a newer version of Tableau.  
Please contact Tableau Software to upgrade your software.
```

Everyone in the office is using the same Tableau version though.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone had changed the report on the server.  The server was version 9.3 but I was not aware anyone was making changes from the server!

Answer (score 1):

Confirm your server is the same version as your desktop. Click in the upper right corner and select About Tableau Server.

[image]

If there is a difference, contact your server admin.

You can also download a different desktop version from here http://www.tableau.com/support/esdalt

Comment: I am the server admin!

Comment: Ha. You can right click and open the workbook with a text editor. Check the version in the XML. Sounds one of your users could have upgraded.

Comment: Yeah I found that hack earlier. (I mean 'hack' in a good way). I just couldn't figure out why it was 9.3 though! I thought maybe it was a symptom of some bug but in fact everything works as it should.